# Stackoverflow when querying document with cycle reference using @DBRef

Tags: java, mongodb, datanucleus, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

My Application uses MongoDb with Spring-Data.

My User.java is as follows.

```
User{
//other fields
    @DBRef
    List<Request> requests;
    }
```

Request.java is as follows.

```
   class Request{
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    @DBRef
    private User who;
    @DBRef
    private User whom;
    @DBRef
    private User group;
    }
```

I am able to save both properly. Say my object user1 contains a list of requests and object request1 contain user1 as value for who. When i retrieve user1 object i am getting StackOverflowError. Details [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-488.). Related [issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-348)

Are there any workarounds to resolve this other than using [Manual references](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/#document-references). Are there any other API's that handles cyclic references correctly.

Comment: Can you explain how that is allegedly related to JPA or JDO or DataNucleus? You're apparently using Spring-Data MongoDB which doesn't use DataNucleus at all, nor JPA, nor JDO.

Comment: @DataNucleus I am looking if DataNucleus can handle the cyclic dependencies. i saw some references to DataNucleus in the following link https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAMONGO-488 .This is the reason i tagged, so that you can tell if I can make use of DataNucleus instead. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Using DataNucleus with MongoDB has no (reported) problems with such a thing. The user in that issue says he was having cyclic problems with SpringData-Mongo, but when he was using DataNucleus he had no problem of that sort (he had an old problem with something else to do with it that was fixed a while ago).

Comment: @DataNucleus  Thanks. i will do some home work. Will have to see how to migrate existing code. Mean time can you please suggest some references about MongoDb Integration with DataNucleus.

Comment: http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/mongodb/support.html  but everything is standard JDO/JPA apart from that, so just use general refs for those

Comment: `@DBRef(lazy = true)` what you need!

Answer (score 0):

Answer : don't use SpringData Mongodb since it has a bug. DataNucleus JDO and DataNucleus JPA have no such bug with bidirectional relations persistence to MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks! Changing to another API is not feasible at this moment. But i will definitely look into this in future. Looking for a work around as of now. And sorry, I cannot accept this as an answer.